# How to check if a non-Win10 PC has Windows 10 Digital License

Tags: windows-10, license

When I was upgrading my PC from Windows 7 to Windows 10 while it was free, it crashed upon reboot, so I was forced to recover to Windows 7 (which still corrupted over 2000 files). Since my PC was connected to Internet during the whole upgrade process, and that Windows Update might have been installed, there might be a chance that my hardware ID was registered on Microsoft's servers even though I had not been able to boot into Windows.

Now my Windows 7 is getting buggy and I want to try out Windows 10's new features. Before I purchase a new hard drive to install Windows 10 afresh (dual boot with partition not an option due to limited space on current SSD), is there any way to check with Microsoft whether my current hardware has indeed been registered as having a Digital Entitlement/License?

Alternative use case might be for someone who purchased a secondhand PC to check if a Windows 10 license has been included or not.

Comment: All upgrades from Windows 7 to Windows 10 provide you a digital entitlement license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for you to find out in this situation is to install W10 and see if it activates, digital license is based on a hardware ID of your PC stored on the Microsoft activation servers.

More than likely it stored the hardware ID during install of W10 if it was connected to the internet at the time of install.

Comment: Which is why I basically updated every windows 7 system I had, even if I intended to downgrade since it would in theory let me upgrade later

Comment: Did the same thing on all my W7 PC's. :-)